# Obter o endereço de Célula Cruzando Worksheets no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

No Book1 temos Sheet1, e Sheet2

Na Sheet2 temos estes valores:

[image: Conteudo da Sheet2]

Na Sheet1 na célula A1 temos esta string: asc-7 ; na célula A2, temos a formula:

`=CELL("address";INDEX(Sheet2!A2:D5;MATCH(Sheet1!A1;Sheet2!D2:D5;0);4;1))` e o valor: `'[Book1 (version 1).xlsb]Sheet2'!$D$1`

Como mostrar somente:  `Sheet2'!$D$1`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode manipular esta string com a seguinte função no Excel em português, em que A1 é o local da fórmula `=CÉL("endereço";ÍNDICE(Planilha2!A2:D5;CORRESP(Planilha1!A1;Planilha2!D2:D5;0);4;1))` e pode ser substituído pela fórmula:

`=MUDAR(A1;1;PROCURAR("]";A1);"")`

ou no Excel inglês:

`=REPLACE(A1;1;FIND("]";A1);"")`

Comment: Perfeito! Qual dos vetores retorna o nome do arquivo? Poderíamos usar REPLACE na fórmula construtora?

Comment: Sim, basta substituir A1 pela fórmula inteira. Fiz separado para simplificar